# How do I write a simple transaction wrapper in a Keycloak SPI extension?

Tags: transactions, keycloak, keycloak-services

By following [this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_single_sign-on/7.1/html/server_developer_guide/user-storage-spi#implementing_userregistrationprovider) Keycloak developer guide, I was trying to write an SPI extension that helps federate a custom user service (think of it as a data store with a bunch of CRUD REST APIs handling user data) into Keycloak.

One basic scenario I wanted to achieve is that when a new user logs in via Keycloak, her/his information needs to be propagated to the custom user service by creating a user entry.

By implementing the `UserRegistrationProvider` interface, I have below method in my provider.

```java
    @Override
    public UserModel addUser(RealmModel realm, String username) {
        log.infov("Adding new user: username={0}", username);
        User user = new User();
        // do something to populate the user object with additional attributes, e.g. those edited via the Keycloak console UI
        UserModel userModel = createAdapter(realm, user);
        return userModel;
    }
```

The strange thing is that this interface method only takes in the `username` argument as a string. I don't know how to access other user attributes. I found below two posts on this issue.

[UserRegistrationProvider value object add method](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-4323)

[Custom federation - webservice](http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-dev/2015-December/006125.html)

The reply from the Keycloak team is that a transaction wrapper can be applied to persist changes only when the transaction is committed. A [good example](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/b478472b3578b8980d7b5f1642e91e75d1e78d16/federation/ldap/src/main/java/org/keycloak/storage/ldap) is the official implementation for LDAP federation. And [this](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/b478472b3578b8980d7b5f1642e91e75d1e78d16/federation/ldap/src/main/java/org/keycloak/storage/ldap/mappers/LDAPTransaction.java) is the source code for LDAP transaction.

But that code portion is too much to read. Appreciate it if someone can provide a simple and succinct way of implementing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading through Keycloak's source code on LDAP provider, I figured out that the data persistence step can occur in a [customised transaction](https://github.com/MaRuifeng/file-based-keycloak-user-storage-provider/blob/master/src/main/java/com/flyer/keycloak/extension/FileTransaction.java) that is [enlisted](https://github.com/MaRuifeng/file-based-keycloak-user-storage-provider/blob/374f2db4310e9829311be4db5f5e9c377b021588/src/main/java/com/flyer/keycloak/extension/FileUserStorageProvider.java#L290) after the main transaction.

The repository referenced above is a file based Keycloak user storage provider I experimented with. Hope it could provide some insights on this.

Comment: Hi, I am facing same exact challenge. Have you write down the simple way of doing this transaction step. I am using keycloak version 9.xx. I really appreciate if you have code snippet. I am storing my user in external database which is mysql

Comment: @Mubasher [This](https://github.com/MaRuifeng/file-based-keycloak-user-storage-provider/blob/374f2db4310e9829311be4db5f5e9c377b021588/src/main/java/com/flyer/keycloak/extension/FileUserStorageProvider.java#L282) is the place where I implemented the mentioned solution. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, Its Working. However I have a different question if you know it, I need to add User Role to User. There are three type of Users can be registered. Admin, Customer, Manager. How to figure out the role. In My Case Add User method was actually invoked by keycloak token exhange as I am implementing social login feature. I provide access token from facebook and keycloak validate it. then it check if user exists in database by email. if not then it called addUser. Here I dont know how to find out the user Role.

Answer (score -1):

> When working with transactions in Keycloak, you can ensure that a
> transaction is fully executed and finished before proceeding by
> following these steps:
>
> 1. Obtain the Keycloak transaction manager: Keycloak provides a transaction manager that you can use to manage transactions. You can
>    obtain an instance of the transaction manager using the
>    `KeycloakTransactionManager` class, typically through dependency
>    injection or by retrieving it from the Keycloak session.
> 2. Begin the transaction: To start a transaction, invoke the `begin()` method on the transaction manager instance. This indicates the start
>    of a new transaction.
> 3. Perform your transactional operations: Within the transaction scope, you can execute the necessary operations that need to be part
>    of the transaction. This can include modifying Keycloak entities,
>    performing database updates, or invoking other transactional services.
> 4. Commit the transaction: Once you have completed all the transactional operations successfully, you can commit the transaction
>    using the `commit()` method on the transaction manager. This commits
>    the changes made within the transaction to the underlying storage.
> 5. Handle transaction failures: If any exception occurs during the transaction, you can catch it and handle it appropriately. In case of
>    failure, you can choose to roll back the transaction to undo the
>    changes made so far. To roll back the transaction, you can call the
>    `rollback()` method on the transaction manager.
>
> Here's an example of how these steps might look in code:
>
> ````java
> session KeycloakTransactionManager transactionManager =
> keycloakSession.getTransactionManager();
>
> try {
>     // Begin the transaction
>     transactionManager.begin();
>
>     // Perform transactional operations
>     // ...
>
>     // Commit the transaction
>     transactionManager.commit();
>
>     // Transaction completed successfully
>     // Proceed with further logic } catch (Exception e) {
>     // Handle transaction failure
>     transactionManager.rollback();
>     // Handle exception or throw it for higher-level handling } finally {
>     // Clean up resources if necessary } ```
>
> By following this approach, you can ensure that the transaction is
> fully executed and finished before continuing with the subsequent
> logic. If any exception occurs during the transaction, it will be
> caught, and you can handle it by rolling back the transaction to
> maintain data consistency.
> ````

---

Creating custom transactions by implementing Keycloak's `AbstractKeycloakTransaction`:

> To extend Keycloak's `AbstractKeycloakTransaction` class and use it
> for your transactions, you can follow these steps:
>
> 1. Create a new class that extends `AbstractKeycloakTransaction`: In your Java project, create a new class that extends the
>    `AbstractKeycloakTransaction` class. For example:
>
> ````java
> org.keycloak.models.KeycloakTransaction; import
> org.keycloak.models.KeycloakTransactionManager; import
> org.keycloak.services.managers.AbstractKeycloakTransaction;
>
> public class MyCustomTransaction extends AbstractKeycloakTransaction {
>
>     public MyCustomTransaction(KeycloakTransactionManager transactionManager, KeycloakSession keycloakSession) {
>         super(transactionManager, keycloakSession);
>     }
>
>     // Implement any custom behavior or overrides as needed
>
> } ```
>
> 2. Implement custom behavior if needed: You can override methods from `AbstractKeycloakTransaction` to add custom behavior or extend the
> functionality. For example, you might override methods such as
> `commit`, `rollback`, or `enlist` to provide additional logic specific
> to your use case.
>
> 3. Use the custom transaction class: To use your custom transaction class, you need to obtain an instance of `KeycloakTransactionManager`
> and create an instance of your custom transaction class within a
> specific context (e.g., a Keycloak session).
>
> ```java KeycloakSession keycloakSession = // Obtain the Keycloak
> session KeycloakTransactionManager transactionManager =
> keycloakSession.getTransactionManager();
>
> try (KeycloakTransaction tx = new
> MyCustomTransaction(transactionManager, keycloakSession)) {
>     // Start the transaction
>     tx.begin();
>
>     // Perform transactional operations
>     // ...
>
>     // Commit the transaction
>     tx.commit();
>
> } catch (Exception e) {
>     // Handle transaction failure
>     // Rollback the transaction if necessary } ```
>
> In this example, the `MyCustomTransaction` instance is created using
> the `KeycloakTransactionManager` and `KeycloakSession` obtained from
> Keycloak. The `begin`, `commit`, and `rollback` methods of the custom
> transaction class will be invoked at the appropriate times to manage
> the transaction lifecycle.
>
> By extending `AbstractKeycloakTransaction` and customizing its
> behavior, you can add your own transaction-specific logic and behavior
> while leveraging the underlying transaction management capabilities
> provided by Keycloak.
> ````

These came from prompts to ChatGPT - I don't know if all this is 100% accurate (for example, I don't see `session.getTransactionManager().begin()` executed in examples, but I haven't dug very deep either) but it seems pretty accurate to me, and it's helped me understand transactions in Keycloak a lot faster and better than with all the Googling I've been doing. I've also implemented some transactions this way and they seem to be working as intended. Hope this helps.

Comment: I appreciate your honesty in citing the source of the information, but keep in mind that  [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831).  I do recommend deleting the answer when you see this.  Thanks!